# Regex match 3 characters followed by integers

Tags: regex

I am new to regex expression and I need a regex in the following pattern:

1. The string must have a format of “TCK#”. TCK followed by integers.
2. For example, This is acceptable TCK123. This is not acceptable 123

Here is my current regex expression:

> input class="form-control" required="true" type="text" name="TCKInput"
>                                              pattern="^[TCK][0-9]$">

With my current code, when the user enter TCK123, it is not acceptable, which is not what I am looking for

Comment: Aman got this right. The missing + is the biggest issue

Comment: Also `^[TCK]` means any of 3 chars T, C or K as a first char.. `^[T][C][K]` at start would have been needed too - that would be an alternate solution

Comment: Use `pattern="TCK[0-9]+"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to below regex:

```
^(?:TCK)[0-9]+$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/h9V7n1/1

Changes in the existing Regex you were using:

> 1) You were using `[`, `]` around `TCK` which means regex has to match
>   any one of the values inside this bracket. As you have to match `TCK`
>   as it is, change it to `(`, `)`
>
> 2) You didn't mention `+` after `[0-9]` which means exactly one
>   occurrence will be matched. However, if you will mention `+`, it will
>   match one or more occurrence

Comment: Note that `(?:TCK)` = `TCK`. Besides, since the pattern is used in the HTML5 pattern attribute, you may omit `^` and `$`, they will only make the regex matching slower. Use `pattern="TCK[0-9]+"`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want all 3 letters: `TCK` and then at least one or more digits after it, then try this:

```
^TCK\d+$
```

If you use `[TCK]` that will only accept one `T`, one `C`, **or** one `K`

### Demo

**This Demo sends to a live test server, so a successful submission of data will result in a response from said server**

```html
<form id='main' action='https://httpbin.org/post' method='post'>

  <input class="form-control" required="true" type="text" name="TCKInput" pattern="^TCK\d+$">
  <input type='submit'>

</form>
```